# Square brackets make WordPress ignore newline/paragraph

Tags: editor

When I insert this text:

Sources:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzPN7.jpg) https://example.com/source-1

[2] https://example.com/source-2

[3] https://example.com/source-3

WP doesn't respect those newlines.

If I remove the texts in [] it renders correctly. I assume WP is parsing it as shortcode and gets mixed up. Is this a possibility? How can I fix this?
It's using the Classic Editor.

-- Edit --

OK the problem actually is that it's generating empty P tags instead of properly wrapping those lines inside Paragraphs.
[image]

Comment: * Which editor are you using?
* Are you copying and pasting plain text or from a rich text source?
I'm not able to reproduce it in block editor, and each line goes as a paragraph.
Selecting classic block and pasting gives same result.
Removing the double newline makes the lines closer (one paragraph), but still shows on a line by itself.
Please state exactly how you do it.

Comment: I was just editing the question. It's using the Classic version, not Gutenberg.

Comment: I made sure no weird HTML is being pasted. I could reproduce it by just typing in the editor.

Comment: OK, I just used another blog instance with the classic editor and couldn't repro, so it must be something within functions or plugins specific to this installation.

Comment: Not able to reproduce in classic editor either.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem and it was Shortcodes Ultimate malforming the HTML in that case: https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes-ultimate/

I'm getting in touch with their developers.

Comment: It seems *only* this wasn't the cause either. Some legacy shortcodes that add empty paragraphs is the culprit.