# Square brackets at the end of a line cause <br> line break to be skipped

Tags: visual-editor

***Note:** Titles are similar but this is a different issue than [Square brackets make WordPress ignore newline/paragraph](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/345042/square-brackets-make-wordpress-ignore-newline-paragraph)*

I'm using the classic editor in the latest version of WordPress. To have the visual editor generate a line break (`<br>`) instead of a new paragraph (`<p>`) I use Shift+Enter. The visual editor shows this:

```
line 1
line 2
```

If I just use Enter, I get this (indicating a new paragraph tag):

```
line 1

line 2
```

The problem occurs when line 1 ends with a square bracket, like so:

```
line 1 [C]
line 2
```

it looks okay in the visual editor but the browser renders it as a single line:

```
line 1 [C] line 2
```

Looking at the HTML source, the first example inserts a `<br />` for the newline while the second example inserts an actual newline `\n` (which is just generic whitespace in HTML and doesn't start a new line).

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: If you are manually calling the post content like $post->post_content and not using the `the_content()` function, make sure to use wpautop OR the the_content filter.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast The template is definitely using the_content().